# I can't get a new password for my gamecenter

Tags: ipod-touch

I have been trying to get a new password for my I pod apple id  it keeps saying message has been sent but i don't receive  I have tried about 20 times please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can always change your Apple ID password on the web at - https://appleid.apple.com/